# Create folders and subfolders in document library using client object model

Tags: 2010

How to create folders and subfolders in SharePoint document library using client object model?

For example:

```
India
   Andhra pradesh
      Hyderabad
        Hitech City
```

Answer (score 7):

### How to create Folder (including nested) via CSOM in SharePoint 2010/2013

```
/// <summary>
/// Create Folder client object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="web"></param>
/// <param name="listTitle"></param>
/// <param name="fullFolderUrl"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string listTitle, string fullFolderUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFolderUrl))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fullFolderUrl");
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    return CreateFolderInternal(web, list.RootFolder, fullFolderUrl);
}


private static Folder CreateFolderInternal(Web web, Folder parentFolder, string fullFolderUrl)
{
    var folderUrls = fullFolderUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string folderUrl = folderUrls[0];
    var curFolder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
    web.Context.Load(curFolder);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();

    if (folderUrls.Length > 1)
    {
        var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderUrls, 1, folderUrls.Length - 1);
        return CreateFolderInternal(web, curFolder, subFolderUrl);
    }
    return curFolder;
}
```

**Usage**

Assume the following folder structure has to be created in `Documents` library:

```
 - Archive
 |
 --- 2008
   |
   --- 09
```

The example demonstrates how to create the specified folder structure:

```
 using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
 {
     var folder = CreateFolder(ctx.Web, "Documents", "Archive/2008/09");
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same ( create the nested structure of folders and subfolders) using ecma script / jsom

Comment: @SaMolPP, surely! Basically this script could be converted or if you have a more specific requirements It might be a good idea to create a separate question

Comment: Vadim, i have posted a new question/thread on this using ECMA script , please throw some light on that question  
 https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237907/create-folders-and-subfolders-in-document-library-using-client-object-model-usin