# Create folders and subfolders in document library using client object model using JSOM/ECMAscript

Tags: javascript, script

Regarding the link below
[Create folders and subfolders in document library using client object model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119796/create-folders-and-subfolders-in-document-library-using-client-object-model/119799?noredirect=1#comment252658_119799)

can i get the same functionality achieved using JSOM/ECMA SCRIPT

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/10610/vadim-gremyachev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example from [original post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119796/create-folders-and-subfolders-in-document-library-using-client-object-model/119799?noredirect=1#comment252658_119799) converted to JSOM API:

```
    function createFolder(list,folderUrl){
        var createFolderInternal = function(parentFolder,folderUrl){
             var ctx = parentFolder.get_context();        
             var folderNames = folderUrl.split("/");
             var folderName = folderNames.shift();
             var folder = parentFolder.get_folders().add(folderName);
             ctx.load(folder);
             return executeQuery(ctx)
             .then(function(){
                 if (folderNames.length > 0){
                     return createFolderInternal(folder, folderNames.join("/"));
                 }         
                 return folder;     
             });
        };
        return createFolderInternal(list.get_rootFolder(), folderUrl);
    }

    function executeQuery(context) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                resolve();
            }, function (sender, args) {
                reject(args);
            });
      });
   }
```

---

The example demonstrates how to create the following folder hierarchy under `Documents` library:

```
Documents library 
   |
 Archive (folder)
   |   
  2018 (folder)
     |
     03 (folder)
```

Example

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
createFolder(list,"Archive/2018/03")
.then(function(folder){
     console.log(folder.get_serverRelativeUrl());        
});
```